# Can you merge an array of object into just one "big" array?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I need to filter based on a search of words,
When I look up one word it pulls up what I need, but I've been having some trouble when it comes to seaching for multiple words that meet the requirements.
So the thing is, I need to keep the previous search and add into this array the next results from the second word.

```
/* ===== Search images by keyword =====*/
searchByKeyword() {
  if (this.searchText != "" && this.searchText != null) {
    if (this?.plansBeforeSearch?.length == 0) {
      this.plansBeforeSearch = this.selectedPlans;
    }
    this.searchTextDivision();
    for (let i = 0; i < this.searchTextArray.length; i++) {
      /* this.filteredImages = */
      this.test[i] = this.planCollection
        .filter(
          (pl) =>
            this.plansBeforeSearch.find((p) => p.name == pl.name) != null
        )
        .filter((plan: Plan) => {
          return [
            plan.id,
            plan.code,
            plan.name,
            plan.gallery,
            plan.tags,
            plan.brand,
            plan.description,
            plan.width,
            plan.depth,
            plan.sqf,
            plan.bedrooms,
          ].some((field) =>
            field
              ?.toString()
              ?.toLowerCase()
              ?.includes(
                this.searchTextArray[i].toString().toLowerCase().trim()
              )
          );
        });
    }
    
    this.filteredImages = this.test[0];
    console.log(this.test);
    console.log(this.filteredImages);
  } 
}
```

I created an array of the words I want to use and for each loop I kept them on this test array. It keeps all images that meet the requirement [image]
But when I pass it to the filteredImages array that is the one that displays the images, I can only pass ONE position. So in the code I shared I set up the first position to show, but I need all three of them!

I thought maybe if I merge all the arrays that the test array has into one array with one position only I can pass that to the filteredImages

Comment: I don't really understand your goal... how do you merge an array into 1 big array if it's a single array?

Comment: Likely flat or flatMap, depending on expected input and output. As it's said, it's unclear how exactly it should be merged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with [`flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) array:

```
this.filteredImages = this.test.flat()
```